# How to search for specific fields in a document in marqo

Tags: python, marqo

i am looking for a way to search for specific fields in a document using [marqo](https://marqo.pages.dev/) because whenever i use the `.search()` method the `_highlights` returns a random field either the title, description or any other field but it is usually random.
this is an example of what i mean:

```
{
    'hits': [
        {   
            'Title': 'document_title',
            'Description': 'document_description',
            '_highlights': {
                'Description': 'document_description'
                               
            },
            '_id': 'document_id',
            '_score': document_score
        }, 
        {   
            'Title': 'document_title',
            'Description': "document_description",
            '_highlights': {'Title': 'document_title'},
            '_id': 'document_id',
            '_score': document_score
        }
    ],
    'limit': 10,
    'processingTimeMs': 49,
    'query': 'search_query'
}
```

as you can see the first documents `_highlights` is Description while the second is title i want a way to make it uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the best way of getting specific fields when using marqo is by add a keyword argument to the search method which is `searchable_attributes=[]` then you pass the fields you want to list as a string.
eg.

```
result = mq.index("your_index").search('query', searchable_attributes=['Title', 'Description'])
```